# Utility or IDE Expert for Delphi 6 that can copy a component and its event handlers to a new Form or Frame?

Tags: delphi, ide, components, vcl

A common occurrence with the VCL is building a component and then filling in its event handlers with code that resides in the host Frame or Form (if the component has Events).  The Delphi 6 IDE is capable of cutting and pasting a component from its host Frame or Form into a new Frame or Form quite handily.  But the code residing in the event handlers on the source Frame or Form is not copied along with it.

Has anybody seen a utility or perhaps an IDE expert for Delphi 6 that can also copy the event handler code too while duplicating the Event declarations in the destination PAS file and updating the destination DFM file properly too?

Comment: This is a great question. I've often thought of writing one as I've never found one that can handle my real applications.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any expert that would grab the EventHandlers code and duplicate it in another host context.
Keep in mind that a simple copy and paste of the code might not work as it would be in a different scope where the available properties and routines are not necessarily the same.
If you need to share handlers between hosts, I'd suggest you put the code in a common unit and call it from the hosts.
Or you can have a base Form or Frame and inherit from it...

Comment: Both form and frame inheritance have been so  problematic for me that I have changed to a pure "composition" approach without any inheritance, where possible, in new applications or new areas of applications.

Comment: @WarrenP.  Re: form/frame inheritance.  Agreed. The IDE's method of daisy-chaining event handler calls from a new instance of a frame back to the inherited or source frame is so fraught with subtle problems that I avoid frame inheritance now and never add new event handler code to concrete instances of the frame if the components belonging to the source instance already have them.  Unfortunately that's a "protect by convention" rather than by code technique making it vulnerable to error.